# Getting the same ID for all rows with a common Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Table like this.

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 5 | Max |
| 5 | Jack |
| 8 | Megan |
| 8 | Dave |
| 11 | Chris |
| 11 | Liam |
| 11 | Bob |
| 11 | Lily |
| 11 | Steve |

I want to get something like this.

| ID | Name | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 |
| 5 | Max | 2 |
| 5 | Jack | 2 |
| 8 | Megan | 3 |
| 8 | Dave | 3 |
| 11 | Chris | 4 |
| 11 | Liam | 4 |
| 11 | Bob | 4 |
| 11 | Lily | 4 |
| 11 | Steve | 4 |

Hope I made myself clear enough.
Is there a way I can do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: OK, and are the values in ID column always increasing?

Comment: No they are in the same range i wrote them here

Comment: I tried everything there is By Microsoft for the Over Clause but I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT C.ID,C.NAME,
 DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY C.ID ASC)AS PARENT_ID
  FROM Table_like_this AS C
```